# Square-based pyramid-The limits of z

Tags: calculus

I would like to ask for your help with this exercise:

We have the square-based pyramid as it appears in the uploaded picture. I am about to computer the volume of the pyramid, through triple integral. 
I have found, according to the uploaded picture that 0<=x<=a and 0<=y<=a (is that correct?) but I have found difficulty in[Pyramid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTYEV.jpg) finding the limits of z.

I would appreciate your help to find the limits of z, so that to be able then to calculate the volume. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You haven't included what the $x$ and $y$-axes are, but I think these limits are not correct. For example, if $x$ goes from a fixed value to another fixed value (0 to $a$, for example), that would mean that there are two staright and parallel walls. But this is not the case ... Certainly, the limits of $x$ have to change as a function of $z$, no?

Comment: The origin appears to be at the centre of the base. The bases is $a\times a$ and the height is $h$. So you integrate $z$ from 0 to $h$. The limits for $x,y$ are $\pm\left(\frac{a}{2}-\frac{az}{2h}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to express this as a triple integral then we have $$\int_{z=0}^h\int_{y=-\frac{a}{2}+\frac{az}{2h}}^{\frac{a}{2}-\frac{az}{2h}}\int_{x=-\frac{a}{2}+\frac{az}{2h}}^{\frac{a}{2}-\frac{az}{2h}}dx\ dy\ dz$$ $$=\int_{z=0}^h\int_{y=-\frac{a}{2}+\frac{az}{2h}}^{\frac{a}{2}-\frac{az}{2h}}a\left(1-\frac{z}{h}\right)dy\ dz$$ $$=\int_{z=0}^ha^2\left(1-\frac{z}{h}\right)^2dz$$ $$=-\frac{1}{3}a^2h\left(1-\frac{z}{h}\right)^3\Big|_{z=0}^h=\frac{1}{3}a^2h$$

In practice, if you did not remember the formula of one-third area base times height, you would get it by noting that the cross-section a (vertical) distance $z$ from the apex is $z^2a^2/h^2$. So integrating from $z=0$ to $h$ gives $\frac{1}{3}a^2h$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your approach was very helpful.